# Enabling Family Library for an app as a developer: Android

Tags: android, android-library

I have an app in the play store which I want to make available for the Family Library of Google. Does our app automatically becomes eligible for adding it to family library or is there something we need to configure for it.

I tried searching about it but I could only find the way to enable family library sharing for the users.
I need to know how can I enable an app for a family library as a developer for my app. Also, is family library not yet introduced to India?

Please bear with me as I have no idea about the Family Library by Google.

Some of the links I have gone through for the same are below which were not that of help though.

- https://www.greenbot.com/article/3102187/android/how-to-set-up-google-family-sharing-to-share-apps-books-movies-and-more.html
- https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-share-apps-music-and-other-content-on-android/
- https://www.engadget.com/2016/05/19/google-family-library-app-sharing/

Please, can anyone help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps purchased after July 2, 2016 are eligable for being shared within linked accounts through the Google Play Family Library, see the [user manual](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7007852?hl=en), this will also explain how to enter (allowing you to see if it is enabled in your conutry). If you want people to allow your customers to share purchases from before that, you have to [give explicit permission](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My app is free and it has in-app purchases in it. As per the user manual suggested by you, "You can't share in-app purchases and free apps with your family members." So, does that mean we can only share paid apps using the Family library?

Comment: @devgeek Indeed, the user manual states: 'You can't share in-app purchases and free apps with your family members.'