# Enable Family Sharing for Subscription in Android App

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

We publish an app on both iTunes App Store and Google Play Store.  The app offers subscription.  To enable family sharing for subscription in the iOS app, we need to select a checkbox in our AppStore Connect account.  In our Play Store developer console, we cannot find such a checkbox.

Does anyone know how to enable family sharing for subscription in an Android app?

Is family sharing of subscription automatically enabled in Android app so developer does not need to do anything extra?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling Family Library for an app as a developer: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275442/enabling-family-library-for-an-app-as-a-developer-android). 

There's also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328140/google-play-developer-console-how-to-remove-app-from-family-library-eligibil